# Migrating SharePoint 2010 Based Workflow to Sharepoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation, designer-workflow

As you might be knowing SharePoint 2010 Based workflow are now retired, Hence i am looking for a way to move them to 2013 based Workflow / to Microsoft Flow - As that's the option left.

Any Help will be Appreciated! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

SharePoint 2010 workflows cannot be 'migrated' to Power Automate. The Power Automate flows need to be rebuilt from scratch.

A guide to rebuild from a classic workflow to a Power Automate process in SharePoint for your reference:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/business-apps/power-automate/guidance/migrate-from-classic-workflows-to-power-automate-flows